# How to highlight 3 line toggle button when i hover?

Tags: html, css

I have 3 line toggle button, when I hover only 1 line is highlighting in blue. How to highlight 3 toggle lines when I hover on the button?

http://jsfiddle.net/s0w5pnmk/

CSS

```
.menu-toggle-btn{cursor:pointer;width:30px;height:30px;position:fixed;top:4px;}
.menu-toggle-btn span{background:#444;display:block;width:30px;height:4px;border-radius:5px;margin-bottom:5px;-webkit-transition: all 0.5s linear;transition:all 0.3s linear;margin-left:5px;}
a.menu-toggle-btn span:hover{background:blue;display:block}
```

HTML

```
<a href="index.php" class="menu-toggle-btn"><span></span><span></span><span></span></a>
```

Comment: This is happening because you have added hover effect on a span. So when a mouse is over a span it become highlighted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change the last line css code to:

```
a.menu-toggle-btn:hover span{background:blue;display:block}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this changing you last line of CSS.

```
 a.menu-toggle-btn:hover > span{background:blue;display:block}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

As other css rules are not specific to 'a' tag. Change it to:

```
.menu-toggle-btn:hover span
{
    background:blue;
    display:block
}
```